# testing .mobile mime format with capybara / rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, capybara, mime-types

For detecting and responding to mobile user agents, I'm using

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

and the approach I'm wondering what is the best approach to test with capybara.  This article suggests setting up an iphone driver with  `Capybara.register_driver :iphone do |app|`

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/

but I'd like a more flexible approach where the mime type is set via the url extension

```
localhost/index.mobile
```

and where I can do this

```
visit user_path( format: :mobile)
```

Rails understands the extension and sets the `format` in the `params` hash, but how do I get the url helper methods to add that to all urls as a file extension?

Comment: the answer lies here -- http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices so i'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to persist the format in a session variable per this Railscast:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices.  I chose to use the URL extension instead of a querystring param because it seems like a better match.

Here is my code in `application_controller.rb`:

```
def mobile_device?
  session.has_key?(:mobile) ? session[:mobile] : request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
end
helper_method :mobile_device?

def prepare_for_mobile
  # avoid messing with .json, .xml
  if request.format == 'text/html'
    # only do this when an explicit extension is present
    case File.extname(URI.parse(request.fullpath).path)
    when '.html'
      session[:mobile] = false
    when '.mobile'
      session[:mobile] = true
    end
    # stop using a session param and go back to letting the user_agent decide
    when '.ua'
      session.delete(:mobile)
    end
    request.format = mobile_device? ? :mobile : :html
  end
end
```

and here is `mime_types.rb`

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :ua      # let the user agent decide
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile  # mobile
```